# Convert celsius to fahrenheit xcode ios

Tags: objective-c

I am creating app that will convert

celsius to fahrenheit and

Fahrenheit to Celsius

i found how to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius

here is the code

.h

```
@interface ctocViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UITextField *Textfield;
    IBOutlet UILabel *Label;
}


- (IBAction)CovertTemp:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)DismissKeyboard:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)CovertTemp:(id)sender {
    double fahrenheit = [Textfield.text doubleValue];
    double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8;
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%4.2f",celsius];
    Label.text = resultString; }

- (IBAction)DismissKeyboard:(id)sender {
    [self resignFirstResponder]; }
```

But i need to know how to convert celsius to fahrenheit.

Comment: This is not a programming related question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a math problem, not programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an algebra question more than programming, but

If fahrenheit -> celsius is (fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8

then celsius -> fahrenheit is (celsius * 1.8) + 32